# Ошибка при очистке таблицы QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Добавляю элементы в `QTableWidget` таким образом

```
while (a_query.next())
    {
        Login = a_query.value(rec.indexOf("Login")).toString();
        Password = a_query.value(rec.indexOf("Password")).toString();
        FIO = a_query.value(rec.indexOf("FIO")).toString();
        Dop_inf = a_query.value(rec.indexOf("Dop_inf")).toString();

        ui->tableWidget2->insertRow(ui->tableWidget2->rowCount());

        ui->tableWidget2->setItem(row_count,0,
                                new QTableWidgetItem(Login));
        ui->tableWidget2->setItem(row_count,1,
                                new QTableWidgetItem(Password));
        ui->tableWidget2->setItem(row_count,2,
                                new QTableWidgetItem(FIO));
        ui->tableWidget2->setItem(row_count,3,
                                new QTableWidgetItem(Dop_inf));
        row_count++;
    }
```

Но когда я делаю `ui->tableWidget2->clear();` вылетает ошибка `sigmentation fault`

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848086/how-to-delete-all-rows-from-qtablewidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На `QTableWidget` не нужно грешить. Вот минимальный пример, и он работоспособен:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QTableWidget table;
  table.setColumnCount(4);
  int row_count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    table.insertRow(table.rowCount());

    table.setItem(row_count,0, new QTableWidgetItem("Login"));
    table.setItem(row_count,1, new QTableWidgetItem("Password"));
    table.setItem(row_count,2, new QTableWidgetItem("FIO"));
    table.setItem(row_count,3, new QTableWidgetItem("Dop_inf"));
    row_count++;
  }

  QPushButton btn("Clear");
  QObject::connect(&btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), &table, SLOT(clear()));

  table.show();
  btn.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Вероятнее всего, где-то что-то вы удаляете более одного раза. Ищите ошибку с помощью отладчика.

**P.S.:** за загадочными именами `Login`, `Password`, `FIO`, `Dop_inf` кроются простые `QString`'и?